# Programming raspberry pi with labview

Tags: raspberry-pi, labview

Do we write code in labview to program the raspberry pi or it's just a gui controlling the pins ?

Answer (score 0):

Coding in LabVIEW is for only commanding the Raspberry PI via a serial interface.

TSXperts have developed a LabVIEW C compiler where the downloaded code will execute embedded and standalone on the Raspberry Pi.

See: https://www.tsxperts.com/labviewforraspberrypi/

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

The direct and short answer is:
You download a firmware which is running on Raspberry Pi to allow communication between LabVIEW and your device ([like Firmata and Firmata client](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-and-LabVIEW/)). The most popular library to do so is [Makerhub LINX](https://www.labviewmakerhub.com/doku.php?id=learn:tutorials:libraries:linx:3-0:raspberry-pi-setup) which you can download from VI package manager that is shipped with LabVIEW.

[image]

So you will deploy an assisting firmware not the LabVIEW code as pointed out [here](https://www.labviewmakerhub.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=894). However, LabVIEW can be downloaded on their hardware like [myRIO](http://www.ni.com/myrio/).

Comment: As described in my answer you can download and run actual LabVIEW code on the Pi using LINX version 3, but only for non-commercial use. For commercial applications NI want you to buy LabVIEW Real-Time and some of their hardware e.g. CompactRIO etc.

Answer (score 0):

The options for using LabVIEW with the Raspberry Pi are currently:

- Use the commercial, third-party add-on from [TSXperts](https://www.tsxperts.com/labviewforraspberrypi/), as mentioned by Dion, to compile LabVIEW code to run on the Pi. This supports [a subset](https://github.com/labviewforRaspi/LabVIEWforRasPi/wiki) of LabVIEW primitives; you would need to check with the vendor whether it supports other LabVIEW functions such as concurrent execution of loops and so on. It does support LabVIEW front panels (i.e. GUIs) on the Pi and as far as I can see supports all Raspberry Pi models.
- Use the free [LINX add-on](https://www.labviewmakerhub.com/doku.php?id=libraries:linx:faq) to deploy LabVIEW code to a Raspberry Pi 2 or 3 (or a BeagleBone Black), in a similar manner to LabVIEW Real-Time. This does not support displaying LabVIEW front panels on the Pi so if your code needs a UI you would need to provide this through e.g. a web interface, or LabVIEW code on a separate PC or Mac. Last time I checked this capability was **only licenced for non-commercial use.**
- Write code in a different language such as C or Python to run on the Pi and communicate with LabVIEW code on a PC or Mac, e.g. via a serial interface or a network protocol such as TCP/IP or UDP.

The first two options allow you to run your code stand-alone on the Pi once you have compiled and downloaded it. For the third option you need a connection to a PC - however that might still be useful if your application is PC-based but you want to use the Pi as a cheap data acquisition interface, for example.